# SimpleCursorAdapter unable to populate TextView

Tags: android

I am working on an application with a portion names ***code for call logs*** which populates takes two arrays and populate SimpleCursorAdapter the application crashes. when I debug the application and check the arrays are populated but stops where SimpleCursorAdapter is created.

code:

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(all_frag, container, false);


          lv=(ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list1);
//code for month dropdown list
        ArrayList<String> month = new ArrayList<String>();
        int thismonth = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
        for (int i =thismonth; i >= thismonth-2; i--) {
            SimpleDateFormat month_date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");

            month.add(Integer.toString(i));
            //String name=Integer.toString(i);
           month.add(month_date.format(i));

        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(rootView.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,month);

        Spinner spinmonth =(Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.month);
        spinmonth.setAdapter(adapter);





//code for call logs
    Cursor managedCursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        if(managedCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
            int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
            String callType = managedCursor.getString(type);
            String callDate = managedCursor.getString(date);
            Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
             String dir = null;
            int dircode = Integer.parseInt(callType);
            switch (dircode) {
                case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                    dir = "OUTGOING";
                    break;
                case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                    dir = "INCOMING";
                    break;
                case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                    dir = "MISSED";
                    break;
            }

            String[] fromColumns = {CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME, CallLog.Calls.NUMBER, CallLog.Calls.DURATION,dir,callDayTime.toString()};
            int[] toviews = {R.id.name, R.id.number, R.id.duration,R.id.type,R.id.caltime};
            SimpleCursorAdapter adapter1 = new SimpleCursorAdapter(rootView.getContext(), R.layout.all_list, managedCursor, fromColumns, toviews, 0);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter1);
        }

        return rootView;

    }
```

**all_list.XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/number"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:layout_above="@+id/type"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/duration"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/caltime"
        android:layout_below="@+id/duration"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_below="@+id/type"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/caltime"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/caltime" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/type"
        android:layout_below="@+id/caltime"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_above="@+id/number"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[LogCat](https://politecuriosity.files.wordpress.com/2013/05/logcat.jpg)

```
05-14 15:32:37.894  32683-32683/com.nm.uzage E/dalvikvm? >>>>> Normal User
05-14 15:32:37.894  32683-32683/com.nm.uzage E/dalvikvm? >>>>> com.nm.uzage [ userId:0 | appId:10326 ]
05-14 15:32:40.096  32683-32683/com.nm.uzage E/AndroidRuntime? FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.nm.uzage, PID: 32683
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3
at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.bindView(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:150)
at android.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:254)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2780)
at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1274)
at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1186)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17594)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:689)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:473)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17594)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1456)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17594)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5398)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17594)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5398)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17594)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17594)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5398)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17594)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5398)
at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:453)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17594)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5398)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17594)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5398)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17594)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5398)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2588)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17594)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2308)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1409)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1610)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1267)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6638)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:813)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:613)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:583)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:799)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-14 15:33:21.647    2721-2721/com.nm.uzage E/dalvikvm? >>>>> Normal User
05-14 15:33:21.647    2721-2721/com.nm.uzage E/dalvikvm? >>>>> com.nm.uzage [ userId:0 | appId:10326 ]
05-14 15:45:07.806    8615-8615/com.nm.uzage E/dalvikvm? >>>>> Normal User
05-14 15:45:07.806    8615-8615/com.nm.uzage E/dalvikvm? >>>>> com.nm.uzage [ userId:0 | appId:10326 ]
```

Comment: crash!. can you post the stacktrace ??

Comment: `length=3; index=3` index starts from 0(0,1,2) so there is no element at index 3. So check the size of the items you want to populate in your adapter

Comment: the array is populated:  String[] fromColumns = {CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME, CallLog.Calls.NUMBER, CallLog.Calls.DURATION,dir,callDayTime.toString()};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Cursor` does not have enough columns..That seems to be the issue. Puth there a breakpoint a look through your `managedCursor` instance.

If you look at the [sourcecode](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.java) where the crash occurs you see:

```
 String text = cursor.getString(from[i]);
```

That means your cursor probably does not have enough columns.

EDIT:

The root is somehwhere else I guess. As Anti correctly pointed out your are using incorrect column names. The array of columns gets however filtered in the `SimpleCursorAdapter` constructor and only valid column names are taken in.

So it's not that your Cursor does not have enough columns, it fails because your `from` (columns) and `to` (views) counts are not equal.

Comment: ok I ve got the point what you say but instead of passing dir, pass the  CallLog.Calls.TYPE and CallLog.Calls.DATE and display them in formated way through adapter?

Answer (score 1):

According to your logcat your code crashes in SimpleCursorAdapter bindView method() with `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3`

If you look at the [source code of that method](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.java?av=f#135), then it will first take the amount of elements in the "to" parameter - this correspondends to your int[] toviews variable - which has 5 elements

Then it loops over the cursor and tries to get 5 elements by index out of it - this however fails at element 3 causing the crash - because apparently the cursor only has 3 columns.

[fromColumns is supposed to contain column names](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#SimpleCursorAdapter(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.database.Cursor,%20java.lang.String[],%20int[],%20int)), and you are trying to pass in strings that are not column names (dir and callDayTime)

One way to solve this is to subclass SimpleCursorAdapter and override the bindView method - you can take the linked source as base and modify it to work the way you need to.

Another solution would be to create your own adapter.